# replace image with another for one second with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that I want to replace with another (same image, but brighter color) to grab the attention of the user to it when he clicks on a certain button, just so he knows that it's there. So I want to replace the original pic with the other twice, for 1 second each, seperated by 1 second as well.

In other words, the user is on the page, he clicks on the button, the original dark image changes to the bright image for 1 second, then back to the dark image for 1 second, then the bright image for one second, and last comes back to the original dark one.

so: original--> replace it (1 sec) --> original(1 sec) --> replace it (1 sec)--> original

I know I have to use javascript for it, but I am very weak in javascript. can someone give me the code for it? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? The purpose of SO is not to just give you the code to do things, but to troubleshoot code you've attempted to write yourself.

Comment: I know, and I know that I am going to get many down votes for my question. but im on a deadline, and I can't afford to spare much time on tasks. I somehow need urgent help.

Comment: you can try with the `setTimeout(function(){//toggle image}, 1000)`

Comment: CSS animation playing with box-model can do too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is a rough idea of one possible implementation, easily improved...the benefit being you only need one image.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMYe5/7/)

HTML

```
<img src='http://phaseoneimageprofessor.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/iqpw29_main_image_.jpg' />
<button id='button'>Start 1 second!</button>
```

CSS

```
img {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
var interval;

function isEven(n) {
    return isNumber(n) && (n % 2 == 0);
}

function isNumber(n) {
    return n === parseFloat(n);
}
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    var src = $('img').attr('src');
    var alt = 'http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png';
    $('img').attr('src', alt);
    var count = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        if (count == 4) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return false;
        }

        isEven(count) ? $('img').attr('src', alt) : $('img').attr('src', src);

    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful so far, I can imagine how the code should look like. Is there a function to toggle image? because it is in fact a picture with different color, that's what I meant by brighter. So I have no other choice than using 2 images! Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zMYe5/6/

Comment: perfect! i can see the animation, but I have one little problem, I am using wordpress, and my images are in a folder brilliantly called images in the child theme, and my script is in a js folder in the parent theme. what is the path to use? or how could I access my image? 

And is it possible to add a delay for the animation? as in the animation starts 1 second after clicking the button.. Thanks again!

Comment: See updated answer, to delay, remove the first `$('img').attr('src', alt);` line. As for your other questions you may be best placed asking another question on SO for maximum coverage

Answer (score 0):

Dryden is correct but we can at least point you in the right direction.

1. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
2. Combine that with a onclick function and document.getElementById("imageid").src="../img/imgname.png";
3. Magic.

If you can't get it working with that, post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can use animation and specifities of box-model while you alternate `padding` and `height/width` to show `background` or not of `img` tag .

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DjhtI/)**

basic coding :

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/9" />
```

```
img { background:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/6);
  animation : 2s infinite blink;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0%, 24.9%,75.1% ,100% {
    heigh:0;
    width:0;
    padding:100px 150px
  }
  25%, 75% {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    padding:0 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can turn the first part of animation into a class and add/delete/toggle this class to image via jQuery / javaScript once every 1s.